# Why isn't my Python 3 code working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to whip up a text editor (spin off of Adventures into Zork) game for my summative project.

This is my decision for the first zone.

```
second = True
while second:
    firstLog = input(">")
```

This is where I am having problems, as when I input "Inside" or "In" the script gets terminated.

```
if firstLog = "Inside" or "In" or "Space Ship":
    print("There is a small " color.Bold + "console " + color.End + "in front of you.")
    print("You can " + color.Bold + "input " + color.End + "or" + color.Bold + "Exit" + color.End)
    second = False
```

Also if I enter anything else it terminates as well instead of printing this and restarting the loop.

```
else:
    "Not valid."
    second = True
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Did you mean `if firstLog == "Inside" or firstLog == "In" or firstLog == "Space Ship":` ?

Comment: Also, your `if` condition does not do what you think it does. You can compare objects with `==`, not `=` and `or` chains multiple Boolean expressions. The expression `"Inside"` is just truthy, because it is a non-empty string

Comment: @Tobias is right. `if firstLog == "Inside or "In"` will always be `True`, but you're using an assignment operator, anyway.

Comment: Related: [How do I test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things. 
The final else you are missing a print statement.

```
else:
    print("Not valid.")
```

The if firstLog should state the variable comparison again.

```
if firstLog == "Inside" or firstLog == "In" or firstLog == "Space Ship":
```

better yet, you could do something like this:

```
if firstLog.lower() in ["inside", "in", "space ship"]:
```

Comment: How embarrassing! Thanks for the help, works perfectly!